# How to assign python requests sessions for single processes in multiprocessing pool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

Considering the following code example:

```
import multiprocessing
import requests

session = requests.Session()
data_to_be_processed = [...]

def process(arg):
    # do stuff with arg and get url
    response = session.get(url)
    # process response and generate data...
    return data

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.map(process, data_to_be_processed)
```

In example, `Session` is  assigned as global variable, therefore after creating processes in `Pool` it will be copied into each subprocess. I am not sure whether the session is thread safe nor how pooling in session works, so **I would like to assign separate session object for each process in pool**.

I am aware, that I could just use `requests.get(url)` instead of `session.get(url)`, but I would like to work with session and I am also considering using `requests-html` (https://html.python-requests.org/).

I am not very familiar with python's multiprocessing, so far I have used just pool, because it came to me as best solution to process data in parallel without having a critical section, so I am open for different solutions.

Is there a way to do it clean and straightforward?

Comment: A session make sense if you have multiple calls in it. I see just one.

Comment: Let's say `data_to_be_processed` would contain 100 000 items, then I would make 100 000 calls on single session... If there would be 4 processes in pool, then I would like to have 25 000 calls per `Session` object.

Comment: And what do you need a Session for (in constrast to just using `requests.get()`)?

Comment: The all the urls I will be querying are on the same website, so I assume it will spare some processing time for my program and site servers.

Comment: Also, as I mentioned before, at some point I would like to use `requests-html` where only session is available for querying.

Comment: You should one session per process,btw i suggest threads when you are doing I/O bound task

Comment: Defining the session inside the initializer parameter in multiprocessing.Pool() may give you what you need, i.e. one session per process.

Comment: @cylim, but how to reuse sessions from the pool?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can use global namespace for sharing data between **initializer** and **func**:

```
import multiprocessing
import requests

session = None
data_to_be_processed = [...]

def init_process():
    global session
    session = requests.Session()

def process(arg):
    global session
    # do stuff with arg and get url
    response = session.get(url)
    # process response and generate data...
    return data

with multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init_process) as pool:
    results = pool.map(process, data_to_be_processed)
```

Long answer:
Python uses one of three possible [start methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods). All of them separate memory objects between parent process and child processes. In our case that means changes in global namespace of processes run by **Pool()** will not propagate back to parent process, neither to sibling processes.

For object destruction we could rely to Garbage Collector, which steps in once child process finishes it's work. Absence of explicit closing method in **multiprocessing.Pool()** makes it impossible to use with objects which are not destructible by GC (like the **Pool()** itself - see warning [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) )
Judging from [requests docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects), it is perfectly ok to use **requests.Session** without explicit close() on it.